# How to create a sector with different azimuths of one point using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, azimuth

If I got one point like this:

```
ID longitude    latitude    azimuth

A   113.38107   22.35215    80

A   113.38107   22.35215    180

A   113.38107   22.35215    350
```

How to use QGIS to create a sector with different azimuths of one point like this?

[image: an example:]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that in symbology as follows:

1. Select composite point symbology with circle and triangle
2. Increase the size of the symbology
3. At rotation field use `Data defined override` and select `Azimuth field` as rotation field

[image]

The output will be like this:

[image]

The circle is not mandatory, you can remove it and use only a triangle, which is what you want:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a single "wedge" symbol apply that as a point layer and then set the rotation value to be the `azimuth` column.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

At present Tool's inbuilt feature with above mentioned process is observed with dynamic size change at variable zoom levels: Below process could be given a try for static output symbols

[image: Sector plot comparison inbuilt vs Shape Tools via QGIS]
[image: Telecom sector making in rendering proper order by QGIS]

You may use "Shapes Tool" to generate variable shapes with overlay of layers by size

1. CSV raw data should be arranged in descending order of Antenna Size to have overlay proper (highest shape size bottom and lowest size on top overlay) or
2. Use Control feature rendering order from Layer properties-->Style and arrange the parameter in order

[image: QGIS: Telecom Site Sector making sample]
[image: QGIS: Shape Tools interface]

[image: QGIS Layer rendering options]